# How to plot train test error for classification models like Support Vector Classification(SVC)

Tags: svm

How to plot train test error for classification models like Support Vector Classification(SVC). I am using SVC from sklearn module, not able to get train and test errors to plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you haven't defined what "error" means, so I'll just assume that you want the log loss.

First, you need to create your `SVC` object telling it you'll want probability estimations:

```
model = sklearn.svm.SVC(probability=True)
```

Then you can compute the log loss given said estimation:

```
probs = model.predict_proba(x)
loss = sklearn.metrics.log_loss(y_true=y, y_pred=probs)
```

Comment: Thanks! BUt i want to plot mean_train_score and mean_test_score values in GridSearchCV for C and gamma values of SVM. How can i do that?

Comment: You can use the `scoring` parameter in GridSearchCV